# Applet JavaCV não exibe vídeo no browser, apenas no desktop

Tags: java, aplicação-web, câmera

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web que se conecta com uma câmera de segurança via JavaCV. O applet que desenvolvi executa normalmente no desktop, mas quando eu tento executar no browser, apesar de não dar nenhum erro, ele renderiza todos os componentes swing (panels, botões, etc), mas não exibe vídeo. A instância de OpenCVFrameGrabber não executa o método start.

Abaixo está o código que uso para chamar o applet de dentro da minha página JSF (Obs.: todas as dependências já estão no .jar):

```
    <applet code="com.br.spacnet.camera.CameraApplet"   archive="CameraApplet.jar" width="1000" height="1000">
```

Abaixo segue o código que conecta com a câmera e exibe o vídeo (estou usando conexão local para fins de teste):

```
    try {

        OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
        jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + "; instanciou o grabber");
        //grabber.setFormat("mjpeg");
        grabber.start();
        jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + "; iniciou o Grab");
        opencv_core.IplImage frame = grabber.grab();

        while (jPanel1.isVisible()) {
            jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + "; entrou no laço");

            jPanel1.getGraphics().drawImage(frame.getBufferedImage(), 0, 0, 320, 240, null);
            jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + "; redesenhou painel");

        }
        grabber.stop();
        jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + "; parou o grabber");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        jLabel1.setText("Erro " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo um conselho do usuário Andrew Thompson, habilitei a exibição do console Java e pude ver vários bloqueios de segurança do JRE. Assim, adicionei as seguintes linhas no arquivo java.policy e funcionou perfeitamente:

permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.bytedeco.javacpp.loadlibraries", "read";

permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.bytedeco.javacpp.platform", "read";

permission java.security.AllPermission;

permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "shutdownHooks";

Para evitar que o usuário final do sistema tenha que alterar as configurações de arquivos do java, a solução definitiva requer a assinatura do .jar do applet. Este tutorial mostra como autenticar um applet auto assinado: http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-applet-auto-assinado-em-java/28660.